# Does react native version 0.61 support android 12 or we need to upgrade to react native 0.66?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-12

**So I need to integrate android 12 support in my application but little confused if the react native 0.61 support the API level 31 (android 12) support.**

I have looked into multiple sources but didn't got any answer for this it seems nobody is getting the same issue means there is a solution.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-sdk": "^0.4.1",
    "@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl": "https://github.com/nitaliano/react-native-mapbox-gl/tarball/master",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^1.4.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.9",
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^3.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.8.4",
    "@turf/bbox": "^6.0.1",
    "@turf/bbox-polygon": "^6.0.1",
    "@turf/bearing": "^6.0.1",
    "@turf/circle": "^6.0.1",
    "@turf/distance": "^6.0.1",
    "@turf/helpers": "^6.1.4",
    "@turf/transform-rotate": "^5.1.5",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "native-base": "^2.11.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.0",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-background-geolocation": "^3.9.3",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-contacts": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native-drag-sort": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^1.1.7",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-fit-image": "1.5.5",
    "react-native-floating-action": "^1.14.2",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.26.1",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-md5": "^1.0.0",
    ...

> package.json file for the libraries I am using.
> any solution or questions will be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

No react-native 0.61 will not support Android 12 because of the default gradle configuration. Which you can change, but its better if you just upgrade. So go ahead and upgrade to <=0.66

Comment: if I opt for default configuration changes then what will be the configs for gradle?

Comment: if you navigate to android/build.gradle you shall see your compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. You can change this to support the version you'd like. However support for android 12 was added in 0.66 so you should upgrade.